# Error trying to deploy Rails app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I get an error when I run `push heroku master`:

```
The authenticity of host 'heroku.com (50.19.85.154)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:f2:87:0c:1f:c8:60:ad.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? 
Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

When I run `ssh -v git@heroku.com`, I get

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to heroku.com [50.19.85.156] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/Sabir/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/Sabir/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Sabir/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Sabir/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Twisted
debug1: no match: Twisted
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:f2:87:0c:1f:c8:60:ad
The authenticity of host 'heroku.com (50.19.85.156)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:f2:87:0c:1f:c8:60:ad.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? 
Host key verification failed.
```

I haven't been able to solve the problem. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your keys might be compromised in some way. Try re-adding them?

run this:

`heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

id_rsa.pub might have a different name on your machine. Check out your .ssh dir before running.

Comment: `My-MacBook-Pro:man Sabir$ heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Uploading SSH public key /Users/Sabir/.ssh/id_rsa.pub... done
My-MacBook-Pro:man Sabir$ `  after i type same error comming

Comment: If you run `ls -al` within the `.ssh` dir does it include an id_rsa.pub file?

Comment: Try adding them via ssh? `ssh-add ~/id_rsa.pub`

Comment: When type ssh-add ~/is_rsa.pub,  /Users/Sabir/is_rsa.pub: No such file or directory

Comment: You have `is_rsa.pub`. It should be `id_rsa.pub`

Comment: My-MacBook-Pro:man Sabir$ ssh-add ~/id_rsa.pub
/Users/Sabir/id_rsa.pub: No such file or directory
My-MacBook-Pro:man Sabir$